C4996 "Py_SetProgramName(name)": deprecated in 3.11
How can I handle the error?
C4996 "Py_SetProgramName(name)": deprecated in 3.11
in the module matplotlibcpp.h in Visual Studio 2022 
and Python312?

Is it possible just to substitute
"Py_SetProgramName" by another function?
What I found so far is: Replace Py_SetProgramName with Py_SetProgramNameUTF8;
When I do this replacement in matplotlibcpp.h, I get the error "identifier not defined".
It seems that my Python.h file does not have it - probably the wrong version.
But how do I get the right one?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
